# Is there an eslint rule to catch space between a block comment and the function/class it is documenting

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am looking for a rule that would not allow this:

```
/**
 * This is a comment
 */

function foo() {
    ...
}
```

And would fix the above into this:

```
/**
 * This is a comment
 */
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/ help?

Comment: As far as I can tell you can only enforce the white line with the rule [lines-around-comment](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/lines-around-comment) not remove it. An alternative would be to use [require-jsdoc](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-jsdoc) to enforce function descriptions

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Prettier.  It's a VSCode plugin, and it has a set of ESLint rules with it as well
https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html

Comment: I agree with using another tool for formatting concerns.